# Как сделать так, что бы обьект(пол) при выходе за границы камеры уничтожался и появляся снова?

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Делаю игру-раннер. Вместо движения игрока используется движение пола. Есть скрипт который заставляет пол всегда двигаться влево. Как сделать так, что бы пройдя левую границу камеры объект уничтожался и появлялся справа, создавая тем самым бесконечный пол и эффект движения игрока?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код движения:

```
public class LeftMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    private void Update()
    {   
        transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: код создания и движения есть?

Comment: А зачем уничтожать собственно? Просто переместите пол с левой стороны на правую.

Comment: @Kromster 
Хочу в дальнейшем ввести генерацию препятствий. Не уверен как это работает, но в моем представлении - при перемещении объекта в исходную позицию с ним и перенесется препятствие, а про уничтожении будет генерироваться заново

Comment: Это уже будет зависеть от вашей игры, собственно (и будет отдельным вопросом)